# How can I get a Rule to trigger a rule

Tags: rules

I need to make a set of eight rules.  Each rule will have about ten actions, nine of which will be the same for each rule (basically, these rules will duplicate a node and change one field).  I would like to create a rule (sub-rule?) that contains the nine similar actions, and then make eight other rules which call the sub rule.  Is there a way to make a rule trigger another rule?  If possible, I would like to do this directly instead of performing an action (such as saving a node) which can trigger an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a Rule Set Component and call it from a reaction Rule.
(https://drupal.org/node/1300024)